# Calculating nutritional analysis with dry weight?

Tags: dogs, cats, diet

I was reading this article about using `moisture` to convert other percentages into their dry matter basis. The article is here:
http://www.dogfoodadvisor.com/choosing-dog-food/dry-matter-basis/

But it doesn't go into how to convert ones that don't end in a percentage.

For example, take [image: analysis for dog food]

How would I convert `Vitamin A 19000 IU/kg` or `150,000,000 CFU/lb` into their dry matter basis? Is it simply `(100%-10%) * 19000 iu/kg` for `Vitamin A`?

Would `Calcium` be `(1.25/90) * 100`?

Comment: Can you include the moisture content of the food in question?

Answer (score 2):

You don't state the moisture content of the food in your question, so I'll use X as a stand-in. When you find the moisture content of the food, just replace that where I have X.

So, first understand that IU is a measurement of biological activity (how much affect a substance has), and kg is a measurement of mass (roughly equivalent to weight on Earth). For materials such as vitamins that are measured in IU, 1 IU of substance A will have a different mass than 1 IU of substance B. IU is not a mass measurement.

When calculating a percentage, the mass of the substance is divided by the mass of the entire food. When mass is divided by mass, the result is a unitless measurement (percent) because the masses cancel out. Because IU is not a mass measurement, the percentage content cannot be calculated. However, we can do the calculation with IU/kg instead of kg/kg.

Dry Matter Vitamin A Content = 19000/(100%-X%)= Result measured in IU/kg.